# working on tree view control in c#

Tags: c#, windows, treeview, contextmenu

I am working on a Windows application that uses tree view .
When i right click on the tree view item it will display a context menu,For some particular command operations the context menu should be disabled

In short how to disable context menu for the tree view

Comment: do you have some code sample or else?

Comment: what is your platform? wpf? winforms? asp.net? silverlight? (etc.?) help us to help you. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no option for disabling concept i think so but you can just show what ever `context menu` items needed as follows  if you have your tree structure defined each and every tree view has a `TAG` or you can define your own `numbers` for this `TAG`. After this try as per follows

```
private void tvwACH_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        tvwACH.SelectedNode = e.Node;
        if (Convert.ToInt16(e.Node.Tag) == 3)
        {
            New.Text = "New";
            contextMenu.Items.Remove(New);
            contextMenu.Items.Add(Save);
            contextMenu.Items.Add(Saveas);
            contextMenu.Items.Add(Remove);
            contextMenu.Items.Remove(addEntry);
        }

        if (tvwACH.SelectedNode.Tag == null)
        {
            string str = tvwACH.SelectedNode.Parent.ToString().Substring(10);
            if (str == "BatchHeader")
            {
                contextMenu.Items.Remove(New);
                contextMenu.Items.Remove(Remove);
                contextMenu.Items.Remove(Save);
                contextMenu.Items.Remove(Saveas);
                contextMenu.Items.Add(addEntry);

            }
            else
            {
                contextMenu.Items.Add(New);
                New.Text = "Add new Batch";
                contextMenu.Items.Remove(Remove);
                contextMenu.Items.Remove(Save);
                contextMenu.Items.Remove(Saveas);
                contextMenu.Items.Remove(addEntry);

            }
        }
        if (Convert.ToInt16(tvwACH.SelectedNode.Tag) == 1)
        {
            contextMenu.Items.Add(New);
            New.Text = "New";
            contextMenu.Items.Remove(Remove);
            contextMenu.Items.Remove(Saveas);
            contextMenu.Items.Remove(Save);
            contextMenu.Items.Remove(addEntry);
        }

        if (Convert.ToInt16(tvwACH.SelectedNode.Tag) == 2)
        {
            contextMenu.Items.Add(New);
            New.Text = "Add new FileHeader";
            contextMenu.Items.Remove(Remove);
            contextMenu.Items.Remove(Saveas);
            contextMenu.Items.Remove(Save);
            contextMenu.Items.Remove(addEntry);

        }
    }
```

As per your requirement you can do as follows you just had to disable or enable the items you did not want this also works fine but `TAG` is important for you

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        treeView1.SelectedNode = e.Node;
        if (Convert.ToInt16(e.Node.Tag) == 1)
        {
            childToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
            rootToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
        }
        if (Convert.ToInt16(e.Node.Tag) == 2)
        {
            childToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
            rootToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```